# Using SVMs for Regression

Tags: matlab, svm, libsvm

I need to use SVMs for regression. 
I have y: a 261x1 vector and x: a 261x10 vector.

I would like to calculate 10 weights such that the weighted 10 values of x at each of the 261 data points mimic the y value.

However, when I run this using the libsvm package, I am getting 261 weights and not the 10 I want.

From my understanding, libsvm requires the x and y vector to be the same length and hence inputting the transpose of x and y will not work.

(Note: this is a portfolio optimization problem and 261 is the number of days, and 10 is the number of stocks)

Comment: Could you please post the code you are using that is resulting in the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I could not understand what 'weights' means but I suggest you to use `libsvmwrite` function to write your labels and feature vectors in the required format. and use `libsvmread` method to get the formatted data to pass as an input.